# Does multitail follow the inode or the file name by default?

Tags: logs, tail, multitail

For `logrotate`d files one usually uses `tail -F` instead of `tail -f` to follow the log file contents. Does [`multitail(1)`](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/) automatically follow the name instead of the inode (which likely changes with the log rotation)?

I sifted through the documentation and also searched on the web, but wasn't able to come up with a conclusive answer.

---

Thanks to the accepted answer I found that the `man` page does mention the option I wanted, but uses the term "descriptor" instead of "inode". So this question and the answer should be the glue for the next person researching the topic.

```
-f Follow the following filename, not the descriptor.

--follow-all
  For all files after this switch: follow the following filename, not the descriptor.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [`multitail` manual](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/manual.php):

```
There are a few other options not fitting elsewhere, these are:
-f  This makes MultiTail follow the file. In case the original file gets
    renamed and a new file is created with the original filename, MultiTail
    will start watching the file with the original filename (the one you
    entered).
```

To me, this implies that by default it follows by `inode` / file descriptor rather than filename.

A cursory reading of the source bears this out; in [`exec.c:79`](http://keetweej.vanheusden.com/svn/multitail/trunk/exec.c), the `follow_filename` var (set in [`cmdline.c:889`](http://keetweej.vanheusden.com/svn/multitail/trunk/cmdline.c) or [`ui.c:966`](http://keetweej.vanheusden.com/svn/multitail/trunk/ui.c)) defines whether the follow-by-filename flag (`-F`, `--follow=name`, etc.) is passed to `tail`.

Comment: Thanks, that's it. I see that yet again it was mys search term which was the limiting factor.